# java binary search with duplicates, returning all the matches

Tags: java

(Using java)I have an addressbook created, and a menu that you can select from within it, to do different things in the address book. Choosing menu item 2, you can search the book for members with the last name being whatever you want to search (inputted from the console).  I search the address book for a last name contained in the book.  There are multiples of some of the names I am searching. When I do my binary search (mandatory its binary) I only return one of the names, rather than returning all the names that match my search name. Here is my code:

```
 case '2': //search by last name// only returning 1 person....

        name.lastName="";
        System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the person you 
                           are looking for.");
        name.lastName = console.next(); 

        int find = binarySearchLast(name);
        System.out.println(find);
        System.out.println(bookMembers[find]);
        process();
        break;


 private int binarySearchLast(ExtPerson  name)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = nMembers; //number of people in the book
    int mid = 0;

    boolean found = false;

    while (first <= last && !found)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        //System.out.println("This is the mid : "+mid);
        if (bookMembers[mid].lastName.compareTo(name.lastName)==0)
            found = true;
        else if (bookMembers[mid].lastName.compareTo(name.lastName)<0)
            first = mid + 1;

        else
            last = mid - 1;
        //System.out.println("This is the mid : "+mid);
    }

    if (!found)
        mid = -1; //it is an unsuccessful search
    // System.out.println("This is the mid : "+mid);
    return mid;
}//end binarySearch
```

The code works, but only returns one of the people with that last name. There are actually (depending on the name searched)as many as three people that can match the searched name. I want all the matches returned.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Just search the list without having a found condition. your found condition is what's stopping the loop, only giving you the first found item.

```
while (first <= last)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    //System.out.println("This is the mid : "+mid);
    if (bookMembers[mid].lastName.compareTo(name.lastName)==0)
        // do something, maybe add to a ist of found names or just print
    else if (bookMembers[mid].lastName.compareTo(name.lastName)<0)
        first = mid + 1;

    else
        last = mid - 1;
    //System.out.println("This is the mid : "+mid);
}
```

Comment: WHEN I DO THIS, I TRIED DOING LIKE YOU SAID AND JUST PRINTING OUT THE NAME, BUT IT GETS STUCK IN AN INFINITE LOOP OF JUST PRINTING OUT THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF FINDING THE NAME.

Comment: First,  I meant to write, Thank you so much! I also should not have usd caps lock there... come to think of it I've heard that implies yelling. My apologies

Comment: So you are currently stuck in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a single `int` value from a method, so, at some point you will have to do additional work.... to expand the search....

The Binary search will not necessarily find the first, or last, or any other specific result... so, the first thing you have to do is - shift to a 'good' spot, which makes sense to be the 'first' match:

```
if (!found)
    mid = -1; //it is an unsuccessful search
// System.out.println("This is the mid : "+mid);
while (mid > 0 && bookMembers[mid].lastName.equals(bookMembers[mid-1].lastName)) {
    mid--;
}
return mid;
```

Then, in your calling code, you can do the opposite:

```
    int findfrom = binarySearchLast(name);
    int findto = findfrom + 1;
    while (findto < bookMembers.length && bookMembers[findfrom].lastName.equals(bookMembers[findto].lastName)) {
        findto++;
    }
    // the values findfrom (inclusive) to findto (exclusive) match.
```